# Assigning a value to a MacAddress variable

Tags: java

In a part of my code, I'm trying to assign a value to a MacAdress variable (`dstMac`). I also have an int variable called `indexMax` whose value can be 0 or 1 or 2 (it will be changed in my program).

Now what I'm trying to do is to assign the value to dstMac based on the indexMax. I mean, if indexMax = 0 then dstMac = value0, if indexMax = 1 then dstMac = value1 and ... *(the name of the variable is chosen based on the value of indexMax)*

```
    MacAddress dstMac; 
    MacAddress value0 = MacAddress.of("00:00:00:00:00:01");
    MacAddress value1 = MacAddress.of("00:00:00:00:00:02"); 
    MacAddress value2 = MacAddress.of("00:00:00:00:00:11");
    if (maxvalue > 50){
         dstMac = value%d, indexMax // Just for showing what I'm trying to do, I know that this is wrong
    }
```

I tried something like `dstMac = String.format("value%d", indexMax);`, but I received this error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to MacAddress
```

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this logic you can use some structure to save you mac values and then choose one from it. Just a sample:

```
List<MacAddress> addresses = Arrays.asList(value0, value1, value2);
MacAddress dstMac = Collections.min(addresses, new  Comparator<MacAddress> {
    public int compare(MacAddress a, MacAddress b) { // some custom logic to choose min mac address, for example
        if (a > b)
            return 1;
        if (a == b)
            return 0;
        return -1;
    }
});
```

Or you can simply iterate it and return first acceptable:

```
List<MacAddress> addresses = Arrays.asList(value0, value1, value2);
MacAddress dstMac = selectOne(addresses);
....

MacAddress selectOne(List<MacAddress> addresses) {
for (MacAddress mac : addresses) {
        if (some condition) {
            return mac
        }
    }
    return null; // if there is no acceptable mac address 
}
```